# How to use HERE API using node? Postman doesn't return the same values

Tags: node.js, postman, here-api

I'm quite new with node and the Here API and I try to use the Here geocoding API to get the geolocation of a point from an address.

When I send the request (as shown in the code below) I get some responses but it's sometime different from the one I get from postman, even with the same endpoint and parameters.

For instance for the address 100 rue André Dubois, Paris, the request path I send through axios is /v1/geocode?apikey=&q=100+rue+André+Dubois,++Paris+ and it returns an empty array, but on postman `https://geocode.search.hereapi.com//v1/geocode?apikey=<MY KEY>&q=100+rue+André+Dubois,++Paris+` returns one item.

Did I make something wrong in my implementation or is there a difference between axios/node and postman?

```
var axios = require('axios');
var baseUrl = "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode";
var login = "?apikey=<MY KEY>";
var qualified = "&qq=";

//list of the adresses we want to geocode
var addresses = [
    {
        city: "CAUSSADE",
        postalCode: "85300",
        street: "impasse de meaux",
        houseNumber: "538",
        format:"FR"
    },
    {
        city: "Paris",
        street: "rue André Dubois",
        houseNumber: "100",
        format: "FR"
    }
];

//return the value if exist, empty string otherwise
var NonNull = function(value) {
    return value == null ? '' : value;
}

//format the request in case of a free text query
var freeText = function (address) {
    var formattedAddress = '&q=';
    formattedAddress += NonNull(address.houseNumber) + " " + NonNull(address.street) + ", " + NonNull(address.postalCode) + " " + NonNull(address.city) + " " + NonNull(address.country);

    return formattedAddress.replace(/ /gi, "+");
}

//create request for qualified and free text. Display then the result.
var createRequest = function () {
    var requests = [];
    addresses.forEach(address =>
        axios.get(baseUrl + login + freeText(address))
        .then(response => {printResponse(response);})
    );
}

// display response
var printResponse = function(response) {
    console.log(response.request.path);
    console.log(response == null ? "response: undefined" : "response: " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
}

createRequest();
```

Comment: I can recommend for you to generate code form your postman API call , just check this link : https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: tip: you can use nullish coalescing instead of `nonNull` method btw https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator

Comment: And thanks Denis for the tip! Always happy to learn about JS!

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, that helps but doesn't exactly answer my question... I still have differences

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was due to the accent on the "e" : é